# Nuxt static pages with Strapi i18n and dynamic deep routes mixes up components

Tags: internationalization, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, strapi

I use Strapi with Nuxt and i18n to produce a static site in English and Danish.
The site should be able to produce URLs like these:

```
mysite.com/
mysite.com/da
mysite.com/news/a-story
mysite.com/da/nyheder/en-historie
mysite.com/cases/a-case
mysite.com/da/case/en-case
```

I have a pages folder structure like this

```
_cases
    _slug.vue <-- for case pages
_news
    _slug.vue <-- for news pages
_slug.vue <-- for other pages
index.vue <-- for my frontpage
```

I use the following code to list links for nice URLs that renders just fine

```
h2 case
router-link(:to="localePath({ name: 'cases-slug', params: { cases: $t('slugs.cases'), slug: aCasePage.slug }})") {{aCasePage.title}}
h2 news
router-link(:to="localePath({ name: 'news-slug', params: { news: $t('slugs.news'), slug: aNewsPage.slug }})") {{aNewsPage.title}}
```

The problem is, that no matter if I click and go to a news page or a case page, I get served the same _cases -> _slug.vue component.

Looking into the .nuxt/router.js file, the routes seems to be generated correct:

```
routes: [{
    path: "/da",
    component: _1ea75fec,
    name: "index___da"
}, {
    path: "/da/:slug",
    component: _2214a27c,
    name: "slug___da"
}, {
    path: "/da/:cases/:slug?",
    component: _3a25cd77,
    name: "cases-slug___da"
}, {
    path: "/da/:news/:slug?",
    component: _3988eeb6,
    name: "news-slug___da"
}, {
    path: "/",
    component: _1ea75fec,
    name: "index___en"
}, {
    path: "/:slug",
    component: _2214a27c,
    name: "slug___en"
}, {
    path: "/:cases/:slug?",
    component: _3a25cd77,
    name: "cases-slug___en"
}, {
    path: "/:news/:slug?",
    component: _3988eeb6,
    name: "news-slug___en"
}],
```

How can I avoid Nuxt mixing up these routes? and the page Vue-components matched to them?

Comment: For a moment I thought that localePath() could be replaced with localeRoute() and then it worked as expected. But alas, it only works with nuxt dev. Upon nuxt generate it didn't work anymore.

I believe it's a bug in nuxt/i18n (v 6.27.2), but I am not sure. The documentation is found here: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/basic-usage/

Answer (score 0):

can you share you solution for the _slug pages data fetching ?

I am using  findOne (slug,_locale:i18n.locale) from strapi  .it's not working
so still hold on this issue

Comment: Sorry @likelovewant, I didn't have the answer yet after all. I have updated the question with a comment about it.

Comment: sure ,thank you same . hope you can find your answer soon